# Exercise with fundamental solution of the heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

I have this problem:

Let $K(y, t) = \frac{-1}{(4 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \cdot t^{\frac{-n}{2}} \cdot e^{\frac{- \mid y \mid^2}{4t}}$. If $v \in C^2 (\mathbb{R}^n \times (0, \infty))$, prove that for $t > 0$ the following is valid:

$v(x, t) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \displaystyle\int_{}^{}  K(x-y, t-s) \cdot (\triangle v(y, s) – v_s (y, s)) \, dy \, ds$ and $v(x, 0) = 0$.

I know that $-K(y, t)$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation. Then:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \displaystyle\int_{}^{}  K(x-y, t-s) \cdot (\triangle v(y, s) – v_s (y, s)) \, dy \, ds =$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \displaystyle\int_{}^{}  \frac{-1}{(4 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \cdot t^{\frac{-n}{2}} \cdot e^{\frac{- \mid y \mid^2}{4t}} \cdot (\triangle v(y, s) – v_s (y, s)) \, dy \, ds =$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \displaystyle\int_{}^{}  \frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \cdot t^{\frac{-n}{2}} \cdot e^{\frac{- \mid y \mid^2}{4t}} \cdot (- \triangle v(y, s) + v_s (y, s)) \, dy \, ds =$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \displaystyle\int_{}^{}  \frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \cdot t^{\frac{-n}{2}} \cdot e^{\frac{- \mid y \mid^2}{4t}} \cdot (v_s (y, s) - \triangle v(y, s)) \, dy \, ds$.

How can I follow this demo?or does this not work? I'm lost :(

Comment: You have to integrate by parts until all derivatives fall on the fundamental solution.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the statement doesn’t seem to be true. There are examples of non-trivial smooth solutions to the heat equation (the famous Tychonoff counterexample), that is $v_t-\Delta v=0$, so in this case you can’t recover $v$ from $v_t-\Delta v=0$ (that is $0$). You should somehov add an hypothesis on $v$ that ensures uniqueness of the solution. Also, the role of the condition $v(x,0)=0$ in the statement is not quite clear to me. As it is stated, it looks like it is true for any function $v$…

Comment: Even more important, you need some hypotheses which ensure that the above integral is well-defined and finite, which is not true in general for $v\in C^2(\mathbb R^n\times(0,\infty))$

Comment: Thanks to both! Lorenzo: I also thought of using that $v_t - \triangle v = 0$, but so the double integral would give zero (no $v$). Therefore I assumed that this is not the case. I will try to integrate by parts.

Comment: I didn’t say that $v_t-\Delta v=0$ in general. I am saying the following. This exercise is essentially saying that, if you have $v$ and you call $f$ the quantity $v_t-\Delta v$, then there is a way to recover $v$ from $f$. This is simply not true in general, unless you add some hypotheses that ensure that you never have a situation with two different $v$ with the same $f$ (that is, $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $v_{1t}-\Delta v_1= v_{2t}-\Delta v_2$), as in genera it could happen.

Comment: And (that’s what I said) there is a famous example where you have two functions $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $v_{1t}-\Delta v_1= v_{2t}-\Delta v_2=0$, where $v_1$ is simply $0$ and $v_2$ is a “rapidly growing” smooth function (that, by the way, is such that $v_2(x,0)=0$ for all $x$).

Comment: Btw… Hint: split the integral in two parts (one with $u_t$ and one with $\Delta u$). You essentially have to integrate by parts in dy twice in the second part (as there is a double derivative in y) and, assuming that at infinity the functions involved go to zero (that’s where in theory you need some hypotheses), you just end up with one term. Then you have to integrate by parts in ds in the first part. This time you end up with an integral plus a term given by the two boundary values $s=0$ and $s=t$. The boundary values give $v(x,t)$, while for the remaining integrals use $K_t-\Delta K=0$